# Negative variance with Delta Method in A/B test analysis?

Tags: variance, ab-test, delta-method

I'm analyzing a ratio metric in the context of an A/B test (e.g. "Clicks / Impressions"). Since the randomization unit and analysis unit are different (users vs impressions), I'm applying the Delta Method to correct the variance.

I'm using the formula from a paper by Deng et. al (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06336.pdf):

$$ var({y \over x}) = {var(y) \over \mu_x^2} - {2*\mu_y*covar(y,x) \over \mu_x^3} + {\mu_y^2*var(x) \over \mu_x^4} $$

In one of my experiments, I got the following statistics from the collected data:

$$ \mu_y=1.3694, var(y) = 0.9411 $$
$$ \mu_x=1.3328, var(x)=0.7622 $$
$$ covar(y,x)=0.9416 $$

This results in $ var({y \over x}) = -0.1065 $ which is negative and obviously incorrect.

What could cause a negative variance like that?  Did I make a mistake or am I missing an assumption somewhere?  If this is just an expected outcome with the Delta Method, is there another variance correction technique I could use instead that always produces a non-negative variance?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: These numbers don't seem to make sense. Let's compute the correlation: $\rho_{x,y} = \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) / \sqrt{\operatorname{var}_X\operatorname{var}_Y} = 0.9416 / \sqrt{0.9411\times0.7622} =  1.1117$. Correlations are between -1 and +1.

Comment: Following up on @dipetkov 's comment - are you sure that's a covariance and not a correlation?

Answer (score 3):

The covariance matrix you're starting with is impossible.

From your question, you're saying the covariance matrix is:

$$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} .7622 & .9416 \\ .9416 & .9411\end{bmatrix} $$

A covariance matrix *must* be [positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix). A quick method to check (for not excessive huge covariance matrices) is to take an eigenvalue decomposition and check for negative eigenvalues. Your matrix has a negative eigenvalue of -0.0942 hence it is not positive semi-definite and hence not a covariance matrix.

I'm guessing you've got a typo or simple error somewhere.

##### Beating a dead horse...

The eigenvector associated with -.0942 is $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}-0.7398 \\ 0.6728 \end{bmatrix}$.

Using $\Sigma$ as a covariance matrix:
$$ \begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}(-.7398 X + .6728 Y) &= \mathbf{v}'\Sigma \mathbf{v}\\
&= -.7398^2 \cdot .7622 - 2 \cdot .7398 \cdot .6728 \cdot .9416 + .6728^2 \cdot .9411 \\
&= - .0942 \end{align*}$$
which is less than zero and impossible.